# Django app login - Can I require user to enter email and password only and then lookup username prior to form validation?

Tags: django, django-forms

I want users to log in using email/password only since their email is easier for them to remember than an app-specific username. But I do still use username elsewhere. Is there an easy way to tweak the auth login view and form to display email and password only and pass in username based on an email lookup? I enforce email uniqueness on signup so the email lookup should only ever return a single username.

EDIT: To be clear, I do NOT want to use email as username. I need both. But I want users to log in with email/pwd not username/pwd.

THE SOLUTION: Prompted by @quaspas's final comment I created a custom url, view and template for login. The template only requires the user to enter email and password. The view looks up the correct username based on the user-submitted email and then uses Django's standard authenticate() and login() functions to log the user in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak your user model to do this. [Have your user model extend AbstractBaseUser with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser) `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`. So now you are using the email as the unique identifier, instead of username. This does not mean you cannot have a username anymore, it just does not need to be unique (but it still can).

Now create a form for your login page that only requires an email and password from the user:

**Form**

```
class MyLoginForm(forms.Form):

    email = forms.EmailField(widget=EmailInput(attrs={
        'required': 'required',
        'placeholder': ('Email'),
    }))

    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'required': 'required',
        'placeholder': ('Password'),
    }))

    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': ('Please ensure you entered the correct email and password.'),
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_cache = None
        super(MyLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if email and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_login'])

        return self.cleaned_data

    def get_user(self):
        return self.user_cache
```

**view**

```
class MyLoginView(DjangoTemplateView):

    template_name = 'my/login.html'

    def dispatch(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect('some-page')
        return super(MyLoginView, self).dispatch(request)

    def get(self, request):
        return self.render_to_response({
            'form': MyLoginForm()
        })

    def post(self, request):
        form = MyLoginForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            login(request, form.get_user())
            next = request.POST.get('next', reverse('some-page'))
            return redirect(next)
        return self.render_to_response({
            'form': form,
        })
```

Comment: Are you suggesting I use email as username? I need both email AND username so if yes, that wouldn't work. I just want to tweak the auth login form/view so that I only require the user to explicitly enter email and password and I get username in the background since it's also required for the form. Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer to illustrate how you would adjust the form. you can still create users with a username, you just don't need it to log in.

Comment: Thanks. Feels like a lot. Is there not an easy way to modify the Login form to display the email and password fields only and populate the hidden username field with the correct value based on an email lookup and then let auth validate username and pwd as usual?

Comment: If you are refering to something more like this example in the django docs, but with a line before it that does something like: `account= User.objects.get(email=request.POST['email']) user = authenticate(username=account.username, password=password)`. It would be better to validate the user input with a form.

Comment: example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

Comment: Thanks. I created a custom url, view and form for login and did as you suggested in your last comment. Works great and didn't break any other part of my app including all the auth stuff.