# Customize user authentication

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-authentication, authentication

Can anyone give more informations about customizing the Django authentication system. Well, I created a custom user in which I use the email as an identifier:

```
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

and I created a custom authentication backend, and I changed authentication backend to this new one in the settings file :

```
    class Custom_Authentication(ModelBackend):
         def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None):
             try:
                user = self.user_class.objects.get(email=email)
                if user.check_password(password):
                   return user
             except self.user_class.DoesNotExist:
                   return None

         def get_user(self, user_id):
             try:
                return self.user_class.objects.get(pk=user_id)
             except self.user_class.DoesNotExist:
                return None

         @property
         def user_class(self):
             if not hasattr(self, '_user_class'):
                self._user_class = get_model(*settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.split('.', 2))
                if not self._user_class:
                   raise ImproperlyConfigured('Could not get custom user model')
             return self._user_class
```

but now i don't know how to authenticate a custom user using his email, do I use :

```
    from django.contrib import auth
    def auth_view(request):
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = auth.authenticate(username=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
           auth.login(request, user)
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/loggedin/')
        else:
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/invalid/')
```

I tried this and it seems that it doesn't recognize the user I created using the admin interface. Are there any other things that I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a custom authentication I would suggest making a form for that. Make a form that takes email and password and then write the clean method to validate the two.

[Try taking a look at this answer as an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006539/django-app-login-can-i-require-user-to-enter-email-and-password-only-and-then?answertab=active#tab-top)